# Multiple identities at the same time using TOR?

Tags: linux, proxy, tor, socks-proxy

I am scraping some websites with curl and I am using Tor to avoid sending too many request with the same ip. The problem is that my app uses threads, so if I send the packet to change identity to the control port on one thread the identity change for all the other threads.

Is there a way I can use multiple identities with Tor?

Comment: Browser version: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/how-to-run-multiple-tor-browsers-with-different-ips On SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321214/multiple-tor-processes

Comment: On StackOverflow I found this answer to be of particular use here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321214/how-to-run-multiple-tor-processes-at-once-with-different-exit-ips>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by identities, and sending a packet to change it.

Using threads means sharing memory space, so if you want to change a variable in your application only for a specific thread, you need to make a separate variable for your thread, or other identity. Otherwise you could change your application to fork a separate process for each identity you use and achieve a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

Why not start multiple `tor` instances and then either connect each `thread` to a separate `tor` instance or spawn multiple `processes` each connected to a separate `tor` instance.

Comment: Care to explain this process a little more @HaykoKoryun?

Comment: Yes, spawning multiple instances solves it. But is there some more effective way (less RAM consumed)?